# Can I can convert this C# code into some Linq code?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have the following `string array` and would like to convert the contents into a linq `Where` clause like the following.

#### I have ...

```
var words[] = new string [] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };
```

#### And would like ....

```
.Where(x => x.Word == "aaa" && x.Word == "bbb" && 
            x.Word == "ccc" && x.Word == "ddd")
```

Cheers :)

#### Update: Why && and not ||

This is actually for RavenDb and it's smart enough to convert that linq to a Lucene query with `AND`'s in there...

So i really need it to be `&&`

#### Update 2: More clarrification why I would like to use && and not ||

The Linq provider in RavenDB, when told to translate the linq to lucene, does the following..

```
.Where(x => x.Word == "aaa" && x.Word == "bbb")
```

get's translated to

```
Query:aaa AND Query:bbb
```

so please, i would really appreciate any help and not suggetions to use `||`. This is not `linq to objects` or `linq to ef`, etc..

Comment: The question is not clear. Btw, you probably meant `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: you mean `x.Word == "aaa" || x.Word == "bbb" || 
            x.Word == "ccc" || x.Word == "ddd"` ?

Comment: a word cannot be "aaa" AND "bbb" at the same time - so your Where conditions would never return a result

Comment: @Pure how can x.Word equal `"aaa"` AND also `"bbb"`. It will always be false.

Comment: Any given `x.Word` will only equal one thing. It will never equal all 4 of those different things.

Comment: @dinah check the updated post. again.

Comment: The downvotes and comments are ridiculous - rather than nitpick here either answer the question or ignore it and move on. It's pretty clear what is being asked - if you don't understand or don't *want* to understand why it's being asked, move along!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `&&` then you're asking for all the conditions to be satisfied.  You could try the `All` operator:

```
.Where(item => words.All(word => word == item));
```

This seems extremely counterintuitive but is worth a try!

Comment: Hi @Kirk Broadhurst - thanks for the answer. I actually did mean `&&` and not `Union`.

Comment: Dude! U did it :) `All` was the keyword i was after :) It was correctly translated to `Query:aaa AND Query:bbb etc...` It was a logical AND. Awesome :) working perfectly now! Thanks for sticking through this emotional question :( Also, maybe clean up the answer??

Answer (score 3):

```
.Where(x => words.Contains(x.Word))
```

**UPD**: this was perfectly valid for initial revision of the question

Comment: Ouch mate. Having a bad day? I was assuming people would see the `&&` and say 'ok .. this is how u do `&&`' .. but as we all know, assumptions are the root of all evil. I didn't say `||`, so please be nice. (The initial version said NOTHING of ||'s .. only &&. You've made an assumption, my friend.)

Comment: @Pure.Krome: we all made this assumption because ``&&`` makes no sense. It would always be evaluated to false, and therefore always return no single element in the IEnumerable...